# npm gives an error TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined at Object.$scope.save

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jasmine, karma-runner

My angular controller is:

```
myapp.controller('newConsultant', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {

    $scope.save = function(data) {
        console.log("assignment data is:" + data);

        $scope.input = data;

        if ($scope.assignment.$valid)
        {

            $http.post('./ccs/enrollment/save', $scope.input).success(function(data) {
                $location.path('/ldp/lem/el');
            });
        }

    };


}]);
```

My controller spec is:

```
    describe('controller: newConsultant', function() {

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller){
        scope={};
        $controller('newConsultant',{$scope:scope});
    }));

    it('check for save function defined or not',function(){
        expect('save').toBeDefined();
    });

    it('check for save function defined or not', function() {
        scope.save(2);
        expect(scope.input).toEqual(2);

    });

});
```

when am test this code karma sent an error:  TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined
     at Object.$scope.save 
          First test is successfully run but i got an error at second one.
Please any one help me. THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: $scope.assignment is not defined anywhere

Comment: controller is works good, but problem is raised at the time of unit testing

Comment: trying setting assignment in test and it should work

Comment: even i got above error